# How can I see my openCV output remotely?

Tags: c++, opencv, networking, remote-access

So I am not sure whether this is the best place to ask this question, but I'll give it a try.
I have some C++ openCV code running remotely. The openCV code draws different thing on the images that are continuously being captured by the camera. 
In other words, when I run my software locally I can just do

```
imshow("some image", image);
```

and look at what my cod draws on the frames.

However now I would like to be able to see those frames remotely, like a videostream. What are the possibilities?
How can I see what is being output by my openCV software?

Comment: Use binoculars?

Comment: @user4581301 you must be the funny guy, I guess?

Comment: Maybe the simplest approach would be some kind of remote access to the machine running your code (e.g. VNC).

Comment: I've never tried it or looked into it, but I assume `imshow()` is X11-based, which means it will display the images on whatever X11 server your `DISPLAY` environment variable points to. So, if your local screen is at IP address 10.0.0.1, you would use `ssh` or `telnet` to get to the remote box and before starting your OpenCV-based program, you would do `export DISPLAY=10.0.0.1:0` then start your program. You'll likely have to do `xhost +` on your local X11 box first.

Comment: I just tried the above again, and it now works as expected - it transpires that the X11 server no longer allows remote connections by default and you need to re-enable that feature in `lightdm.conf` (on Ubuntu at least).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a videostream remotely then you can use GStreamer to create a pipeline over the network. For that you can use `cv::VideoWriter` to write the frames to GStreamer pipeline.

```
cv::VideoWriter writer;
writer.open("appsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=localhost port=9999", 0, (double)30, cv::Size(640, 480), true);

if (!writer.isOpened()) {
    printf("=ERR= can't create video writer\n");
    return -1;
}

while (true) {

    /* Process the frame here */

    writer << frame;
}
```

You can change `localhost` with the ip of your remote machine. On the receiving machine you can use the following command `gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=9999 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink`

For more information on GStreamer you can see this [link](http://www.z25.org/static/_rd_/videostreaming_intro_plab/).

Comment: Unfortunately I always get "=ERR= can't create video writer", any idea what I can do to solve this issue? I am using a logitech webcam, if that helps.

Comment: Do you have gstreamer installed? I'd recommend first trying gstreamer without opencv using the commands in the link I gave.

Comment: Sorry but I am totally lost about how to set up that stuff.... Any good tutorials you can recommend me?

Comment: Refer to this link for setting up GStreamer:http://www.z25.org/static/_rd_/videostreaming_intro_plab/

Answer (score 0):

By using tcp socket programming you can send the image meta data over network. There is a project sable-netcv at https://code.google.com/archive/p/sable-netcv/ , you can try it out.

Comment: When I try to compile the server side code I get multiple errors, I can't solve like: error 'usleep' was not declared in this scope.

Comment: if your platform is linux then you need to include  #include <unistd.h>